# React Native Android module, accessing children props

Tags: android, react-native

I m trying to write a React Native module using Android native (and Java) and I m facing problem when trying to access child views.

For now, when I try to log my children when setting my `ReactProp`, there are 0 children :

```
@ReactProp(name = "name")
public void setName(ReactViewGroup view, String name) {
    Log.e("Do we have childs ?", view.getChildCount()+ ""); // 0
}
```

From the javascript side :

```
<NativeAndroidComponent name="superName">
  <Text>Hello world</Text> // this one is well displayed on the screen
</NativeAndroidComponent>
```

I actually don't know how I can access my `props.children` from the native side.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Did you finally figure this out? :)

Comment: Well.. Not at all ^^'

Comment: Haha, sad to hear. A guess it should be possible to do similar to how Scrollview implementation works.